# strong winds are tipped

Tags: vocabulary

> The day dawned beautiful, mild, and still at Flemington Racecourse. But it won't last: strong winds **are tipped** before the running of the Melbourne Cup. ([Aussie ABC](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2014/s4120970.htm))

What does 'tip' mean in the context? It sounds like 'the wind blows.' But I can't find the meaning  on dictionaries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Strong winds are tipped before the running of the Melbourne Cup.

This is a play on the word *tip*. The Melbourne Cup is a horse racing event. In horse racing and other sports, people try to predict who is going to win. If someone knowledgeable about horse racing gives you a 'tip', it means they give you some special advice about who will win. This means that if you bet on that horse, maybe you will have a good chance of winning.

If lots of people think a horse is going to win a race, people say that horse is *tipped* to win. Sometimes we use this language from racing to talk about other events that are difficult to predict, for example elections, or the weather. If knowledgeable people, who know a lot about politics, say that a candidate is going to win, we can say that *that candidate is tipped to win*.

In the original Poster's example, *strong winds are tipped* means that people who predict the weather think that there are going to be strong winds. The writer has borrowed language from the world of horse racing. This is an interesting bit of language to use here, because the Melbourne Cup is a horse race!

Answer (score 5):

It means that someone believes there will be strong winds before the running of the Melbourne Cup. The statement could be expressed alternatively as

> Strong winds are expected before the running of the Melbourne Cup.
>
> Strong winds are forewarned before the running of the Melbourne Cup.

This usage aligns with two less common uses of *[tip](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tip#tip-3)*; as ODO has it:

> ***tip*** (3): noun
>
> noun
>   2. A small but useful piece of practical advice:
>    2.1 A prediction or piece of expert information about the likely winner of a race or contest
>
> verb
>   2. *British* Predict as likely to win or achieve something
>   3.  (tip someone off) informal Give someone information in a discreet or confidential way

Comment: But this usage doesn't align precisely with the usual verbal usage of this sense, which requires 3 syntactic arguments: [They] tipped [him] [to win]).